# Greenplum - Update statement failing on timestamp column

Tags: greenplum, hawq

We have source and target table in greenplum database. we are comparing both the table using sql script.
But Update is not working here. and it is not updating the timestamp column of target table with respect to source table.

**Input - Source/target table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE sysprocompanyb.target_customer_table
(

  time timestamp without time zone,
  "Customer" character(20),
  )
DISTRIBUTED BY ("ID");
```

**Noted this**

However found this, on Execution of below update statement it is not throwing any error. it is saying Updated all rows successfully. But when i am checking after process completion  target timestamp column field is not equal to source timestamp column field.

**We tried :**

```
 BEGIN;
insert into schemaname.target_customer_table select s.* from schemaname.source_customer_table s LEFT JOIN schemaname.target_customer_table d ON s."Customer"=d."Customer" where d."Customer" is null;
UPDATE schemaname.target_customer_table d 
SET "time" = d."time"
FROM schemaname.source_customer_table s 
WHERE s."Customer" = d."Customer";
```

**Output**

We want to match source and target column after completion of above SQL Transaction.

Any help on it would be much appreciated?

Comment: You are setting "time", which is the target of your update, to the value of d."time" which again is the target of your update.  So you are updating the column to be the same value as before.  I'm guessing you want to change "time" to s."time".

Comment: @JonRoberts   Got the issue.  Thank you.